# Converting java app from using TomEE to using TomEE+, currently using Hibernate 4, JPA queries stopped working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, tomee-7

Converted java app from using TomEE to using TomEE+, currently using Hibernate 4, JPA queries stopped working. I get the following error when I ran a SELECT JPA query:

```
WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: -5501, SQLState: 42501
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - user lacks privilege or object not found: <Database table object name>
```

This was NOT happening when I used TomEE with Dozer. Dozer was taken out and excluded from the newly converted app. Need to know what i need to do to make this work.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `tomee.xml` or which datasources are defined in there? Did you port it to the new environment?